# What are the rules for ppp objects? Is selecting two variables possible for an sapply function?

Tags: r, spatstat

Working with code that describes a poisson cluster process in spatstat. Breaking down each line of code one at a time to understand. Easy to begin.

```
library(spatstat)
lambda<-100
win<-owin(c(0,1),c(0,1))
n.seeds<-lambda*win$xrange[2]*win$yrange[2]
```

Once the window is defined I then generate my points using a random generation function

```
x=runif(min=win$xrange[1],max=win$xrange[2],n=pmax(1,n.seeds))
y=runif(min=win$yrange[1],max=win$yrange[2],n=pmax(1,n.seeds))
```

This can be plotted straight away I know using the ppp function

```
seeds<-ppp(x=x,
y=y,
window=win)

plot(seeds)
```

The next line I add marks to the ppp object, it is apparently describing the angle of rotation of the points, I don't understand how this works right now but that is okay, I will figure out later.

```
marks<-data.frame(angles=runif(n=pmax(1,n.seeds),min=0,max=2*pi))
seeds1<-ppp(x=x,
           y=y,
           window=win,
           marks=marks)
```

The first problem I encounter is that an objects called pops, describing the populations of the window, is added to the ppp object. I understand how the values are derived, it is a poisson distribution given the input value mu, which can be any value and the total number of observations equal to points in the window.

```
seeds2<-ppp(x=x,
            y=y,
            window=win,
            marks=marks,
            pops=rpois(lambda=5,n=pmax(1,n.seeds)))
```

My first question is, how is it possible to add a variable that has no classification in the ppp object? I checked the ppp documentation and there is no mention of pops.

The second question I have is about using double variables, the next line requires an sapply function to define dimensions.

```
dim1<-pmax(1,sapply(seeds1$marks$pops, FUN=function(x)rpois(n=1,sqrt(x))))
```

I have never seen the $ function being used twice, and seeds2$marks$pop returns $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. Could you explain what is going on here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's several questions - please ask one question at a time.

From your post it is not clear whether you are trying to understand someone else's code, or developing code yourself. This makes a difference to the answer.

Just to clarify, this code does not come from inside the `spatstat` package; it is someone's code using the `spatstat` package to generate data. There is code in the `spatstat` package to generate simulated realisations of a Poisson cluster process (which is I think what you want to do), and you could look at the `spatstat` code for `rPoissonCluster` to see how it can be done correctly and efficiently.

The code you have shown here has numerous errors. But I will start by answering the two questions in your title.

1. The rules for creating `ppp` objects are set out in the help file for `ppp`. The help says that if the argument `window` is given, then unmatched arguments `...` are ignored. This means that in the line `seeds2<-ppp(x=x,y=y,window=win,marks=marks,pops=rpois(lambda=5,n=pmax(1,n.seeds)))`
   the argument `pops` will be *ignored*.
2. The idiom `sapply(seeds1$marks$pops, FUN=f)` is perfectly valid syntax in R. If the object `seeds1` is a structure or list which has a component named `marks`, which in turn is a structure or list which has a component named `pops`, then the idiom `seeds1$marks$pops` would extract it. This has nothing particularly to do with `sapply`.

Now turning to errors in the code,

- The line `n.seeds<-lambda*win$xrange[2]*win$yrange[2]` is presumably meant to calculate the expected number of cluster parents (cluster seeds) in the window. This would only work if the window is a rectangle with bottom left corner at the origin (0,0). It would be safer to write `n.seeds <- lambda * area(win)`.
- However, the variable `n.seeds` is used later as it it were the number of cluster parents (cluster seeds). The author has forgotten that the number of seeds is random with a Poisson distribution. So, the more correct calculation would be `n.seeds <- rpois(1, lambda * area(win))`
- However this is still not correct because cluster parents (seed points) outside the window can also generate offspring points inside the window. So, seed points must actually be generated in a larger window obtained by expanding `win`. The appropriate command used inside `spatstat` to generate the cluster parents is `bigwin <- grow.rectangle(Frame(win), cluster_diameter) ; Parents <- rpoispp(lambda, bigwin)`
- The author apparently wants to assign two mark values to each parent point: a random `angle` and a random number `pops`. The correct way to do this is to make the `marks` a data frame with two columns, for example `marks(seeds1) <- data.frame(angles=runif(n.seeds, max=2*pi), pops=rpois(n.seeds, 5))`